How to trim the string right side with a reference?
I'm currently writing a formula in a Flow which picks out a email string from a Description field. This is the current formula :
MID({!$Record.Description}, FIND("Archiver Email:",{!$Record.Description})+16,75)
So, I'm returning 75 characters after the label which is more than enough.
But my string will inevitably be something like : "john.smith@gmail.com   other description text..."
My update : I'm using this formula to trim everything LEFT of the end space of the email :
LEFT({!var_archiveremaildefault}, FIND("  ", {!var_archiveremaildefault}) -1)
And somehow this does not work. I have noticed FIND does not land on a space or even land on '.com' if I use that. FIND will land on single characters such as "." or "@" but won't find ".com" for some reason.
How can I trim everything to the right of the '.com' in the string that will be returned ? I'm trying to figure out the best method. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

What if the email address doesn't end in ".com", like ".gov" or something else?

You need to find the starting and ending positions of the email text so you can extract it with MID.  It looks like you have a fixed start position, so you can use FIND(".com", yourstring) + 5 to give you the end position, then MID(yourstring, 16, end) to extract.
If you don't have a fixed starting position, this probably can't be done with flow formula, and you'll have to use Apex regex pattern and matcher functionality.
